# How to get GMT timeoffset value for current time in Dart/Flutter

Tags: date, flutter, dart, time, gmt

I'm developing an application where I need to get only GMT offset time, i.e. for India +5.30. How do I achieve this dart.

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var timezoneOffset=now.timeZoneOffset;
print (timezoneOffset);
//console : 05:30:00
```

how to get +/- GMT offset?

Comment: That is the offset giving to you.
You said the offset for india is +5:50 and the console printed out `05:30:00` which is exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

The `timeZoneOffset` gives you the difference between the timezone of your device and UTC.

Since `UTC` is the same time with `GMT` then `timeZoneOffset` give you the `+/- GMT offset` you need.

In your Question, you said the offset for India is `+5.30` and when you printed `print(timezoneOffset)` it gave you `05:30:00` which is exactly the `5:30` offset you needed.

Comment: yes, but how do I get in format GMT +5.5hrs instead of 05:30:00 hours

Comment: Have you find any possible solution for this @MohammedSadakathAliAamiri

Answer (score 0):

```
int minutes = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inMinutes;

print(minutes);

int hours = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inHours;

print(hours);
```

More info at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneOffset.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime class.

```
DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset; // return Duration()

DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inHours; // return int

DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset.inMinutes; // return int
```

Answer (score 0):

Its in dart/flutter hope you can convert

```dart
var t = DateTime.now();
t = t.add(const Duration(minutes: 1));
print(t.timeZoneName);
var add = t.hour.toString()+":"+t.minute.toString()+":"+t.second.toString();
        'send_after':'Sept ${t.day} ${t.year} ${add} ${t.timeZoneName}'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Import it](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone)

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart';

void main() async { 
  initializeTimeZones(); 
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart';

 Future<void> timeZoneInz() async {
    await initializeTimeZone();
  }

  var detroit = getLocation('Asia/Tashkent');

 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    timeZoneInz(); 
  }

Text(TZDateTime.now(detroit).toString());
```

See [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for more database entry names.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.now().toLocal().timeZoneName;
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

//GMT+09:00
String _getTimeZoneOffset() {
Duration duration = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset;
String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
String twoHour = twoDigits(duration.inHours);
String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
if(duration.inMinutes >0){
return "GMT+${twoHour}:${twoDigitMinutes}";
}
return "GMT-${twoHour}:${twoDigitMinutes}";
}